# Aumentar altura e largura auto dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Criei umas divs dinamicamente em javascript. Tenho a div com o tamanho em auto. O problema é que a div corta uma parte do circulo. Como posso reslver isso, sem por valores de pixeis.

```
div.style.height = "auto";
```

exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/20/

Answer (score 1):

Não é a DIV que está cortando, mas o SVG que está com o atributo `height="42"` e acaba cortando o gráfico.